# event handler - how to identify which page triggered the event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an infinite scroll which behaves slightly differently depending on which page triggers it. How can I identify which page triggered the `.scroll` event from inside the `.scroll` event handler?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

  if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){

       if page 1 is the one where window.scrollTop happened, then do this {

       }

       if page 2 is the one where window.scrollTop happened, then do this {

       }
  }

})
```

---

Additional issue: I'm using a lot of AJAX and the URL doesn't change between those 2 pages.

Comment: adding a unique `id` per page will be a good thing to start.

Comment: @roullie please elaborate a little more ... where can I place the unique `id`? In the `body` tag?

Comment: you could also use the page url `window.location.href`.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ good idea but it won't work in my case because I'm using a lot of AJAX and the URL doesn't change between those 2 pages.

Comment: @user1883050 So you can have a global variable then which indicates which page you are on? Every time an ajax call finishes, change that global variable ... and in your function, just check the value of that variable.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ that's a good idea... I think that can work.